# AutoMapper mapping 0 when the source field is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have a Foreign Key that allows null in my EntityModel. I am using Automapper to map my ViewModel to the EntityModel. If the user leaves the field control (combobox) empty, AutoMapper is mapping that to 0, which is throwing a referential integrity error.

Is there a way to leave null values as they are?

Update:

Below are my objects (the field of interest is SalutationId)

```
public class UserVM
{
    public long UserId {get;set;}

    [Display(Name = "Salutation:")]
    public long SalutationId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The First Name field is required!")]
    [Display(Name = "* First Name:")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Last Name field is required!")]
    [Display(Name = "* Last Name:")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class tblUser
{
    public long UserId;
    public Nullable<System.Int64> SalutationId;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;

}
```

Comment: And the property corresponding to the foreign key is a nullable type ? Can you show your classes, maybe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the user leaves the field control (combobox) empty

`SalutationId` in the `UserVM` will be set to its default value then, which is 0. Automapper works as expected, because it maps 0 -> 0.

You have to make `SalutationId` nulabble in the ViewModel also.